# Angular i18n dynamic translation in case id is known

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

First of all I do understand that I am using AOT compilation and this is static. Although, I was wondering if it is possible to load the correct translation if the ID is known (and defined in a `source.{language}.xlf` file)?

In general I need to gain more understanding of what is going on under the hood, more specifically how does Angular recognises the placeholder to replace?

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- Backend returns an error code (eg. 'error_code');
- error_code is added to xlf files;
- Dynamic error component is created to display translated error messages;
- At this point I am stuck. I do have the ID of the translated element but I think I am missing the last piece of the puzzle.

The following has been tried without any luck:

`<p class="message message--warning" i18n="{{error}}"> /* {{error}} = error_code */
    {{error}}
  </p>`

I played a bit around with the `select` options but this does not seem to work as well.

It would be great if someone is able to point me in the right direction.

## EDIT

Currently I have this:

html file:

```
<span i18n="@@error-message">
      {error, select,
        invalid.phone { invalid.phone }
        invalid.name { invalid.name }
        ...
      }
</span>
```

xlf file

```
<trans-unit id="error-message" datatype="html">
    <source><x id="ICU" equiv-text="{error, select, invalid.phone {...} invalid.name {...}}"/></source>
    <target><x id="ICU" equiv-text="{error, select, invalid.phone {...} invalid.name {...}}"/></target>
</trans-unit>

<trans-unit id="7cefd72dcdd90f3149190b11f35dd151b0abd193" datatype="html">
    <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, invalid.phone {invalid.phone } invalid.name {invalid.name }}</source>
    <target>{VAR_SELECT, select, invalid.phone {Invalid phone} invalid.name {Invalid name}}</target>
</trans-unit>
```

Basically I have 2 questions left:

- Is it possible to make the HTML part more generic like:

```
<span i18n="@@error-message">
      {error, select, error { error }}
</span>
```

- Is it possible to extract the translations into separate `trans-unit` elements like:

```
<trans-unit id="7cefd72dcdd90f3149190b11f35dd151b0abd193" datatype="html">
    <source>{VAR_SELECT, select, invalid.phone {invalid.phone } invalid.name {invalid.name }}</source>
    <target>{VAR_SELECT, select, invalid.phone {message.invalid.phone} invalid.name {message.invalid.name}}</target>
</trans-unit>

<trans-unit id="message.invalid.name" datatype="html">
    <source>invalid.name</source>
    <target>Invalid name</target>
</trans-unit>
```

This will make it more maintainable.

Comment: Why do you want to add the error code to the xlf files? Can't you just create an ICU expression that has al possible error messages for that call?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Currently I have implemented the messages with a select (switch statement in most programming languages), but I do not think this is maintainable. I envision to reference to other trans-unit elements within the select. Am I missing something or is this 'the way to go'? I have updated the question with the solution I have found so far.

Comment: @David forgot to tag you. Sorry

Comment: Sorry I dont know enough about translations to answer that. Angular should soon allow translating strings in code files. Maybe you could organise it better that way